# Compiled library's headers not being able to reach each other

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, static-libraries, header-files

I'm having an issue regarding the library called JSBSim. The library itself is not so relevant, but the issues are surrounding multiple cases of cyclic dependency in the header files.

Background info:

Running CentOS 7 64 bit - libraries are statically linked with headers located in usr/local/include and corresponding .a and .la in usr/local/lib

The directory structure for /usr/local/include/JSBSim is as followed:

```
initialization
input_output
math
models
simgear
FGFDMExec.h
FGJSBBase.h
```

I'm running a makefile with the following content:

```
all:
    g++ *.cpp -lJSBSim -o output

clean:
    /bin/rm -f output
```

I'm writing a wrapper for the JSBSim with the basic following skeleton:

```
#include <JSBSim/FGFDMExec.h>

class JsbSimWrapper
{
};
```

I get the following error when I run the makefile:

```
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/local/include/JSBSim/FGFDMExec.h:47:0,
                 from JsbSimWrapper.hpp:7,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/JSBSim/initialization/FGTrim.h:53:23: fatal error: FGFDMExec.h: No such file or directory
 #include "FGFDMExec.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The errors don't come from the class itself; rather the inclusion of the main header file of the library. I did some investigating, and the file FGTrim.h is located in initialization, and in FGTrim's include's:

```
#include "FGFDMExec.h"
```

It looks like FGTrim can't see FGFDMExec.h because it's down a directory, but FGFDMExec.h can see FGTrim just fine because in FGFDMExec.h has the following include:

```
#include "initialization/FGTrim.h"
```

Is there any way to get around this? I really don't want to have to reorganize the header structure or rewrite the headers and recompile the library if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `-I/usr/local/include/JSBSim/initialization` to the `CXXFLAGS` in your makefile.

Comment: ^ To your compiler call respectively.

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately to no success.

Comment: You need to add `-I/usr/local/bin/JSBSim` (note no `initialization` at the end) to your compile line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

I edited my makefile to the following:

```
JSBSIM=/usr/local/include/JSBSim
CXXFLAGS=-I$(JSBSIM)
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/initialization
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/simgear/xml
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/simgear
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/models/atmosphere
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/models/propulsion
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/models/flight_control
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/models
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/input_output
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(JSBSIM)/math

output: main.cpp JsbSimWrapper.cpp
    g++ main.cpp JsbSimWrapper.cpp $(CXXFLAGS) -lJSBSim -o output
clean:
    /bin/rm -f output
```

Hopefully that helps somebody!

Comment: I'd be surprised if you really needed anything other than the first line here `-I$(JSBSIM)`.  If you really need all these, then the header files for this package are badly malformed.